# How to give nmap a key variable in Vim?

Tags: vim

I just got answer to jump to the line start with given character by typing

<kbd>/</kbd> + ^[character]

But I thought it's not as fast as <kbd>f</kbd> to jump to character in a line. so i'm want to map it to a key combination like

<kbd>go</kbd> + [character]

by doing something like in the `.vimrc`

`nmap go<expr> /^<expre>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See `:help map-expression`; you can query a single character with `getchar()`:

```
:nnoremap <expr> go '/^' . nr2char(getchar()) . '<CR>'
```

Answer (score 0):

it is hard to map this function directly. because the letter/character could be anything.

But this small function may work for you:

```
function! GoToLine()
    call inputsave()
    let c= input('Enter chars:')
    call inputrestore()
    call search ('^' . c)
    let @/ = '^'.c
endfunction
```

you can map for example:

```
nnoremap <leader>go call GoToLine()
```

then enter chars you need, the function will bring you there. In this way you could enter more than one chars.

hope it helps.